# Pass values into scrapy callback

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I'm trying to get started crawling and scraping a website to disk but having trouble getting the callback function working as I would like.

The code below will visit the start_url and find all the "a" tags on the site. For each 1 of them it will make a callback which is to save the text response to disk and use the crawerItem to store some metadata about the page.

I was hoping someone could help me figure out how to pass

1. a unique id to each callback so it can be used as the filename when saving the file
2. Pass the url of the originating page so it can be added to the metadata via the Items
3. Follow the links on the child pages to go another level deeper into the site

Below is my code thus far

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from mycrawler.items import crawlerItem

class CrawlSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "librarycrawler"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.example.com"
    ]

    rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(),callback='scrape_page', follow=True)
)

def scrape_page(self,response):
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body,"html.parser")
    ScrapedPageTitle = page_soup.title.get_text()
    item = LibrarycrawlerItem()
    item['title'] =ScrapedPageTitle
    item['file_urls'] = response.url

    yield item
```

**In Settings.py**

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = [
    'librarycrawler.files.FilesPipeline',
]
FILES_STORE = 'C:\Documents\Spider\crawler\ExtractedText'
```

**In items.py**

```
import scrapy


class LibrarycrawlerItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    Files = scrapy.Field()
```

Comment: what does the originating page means ?

Comment: The parent page or to put it another way the page that had the link which resulting in the callback so say example.com had link 1, link 2, link 3 the originating page for link1,link2,link3 would be example.com

Comment: You can't choose the name of the files you're saving using scrapy

Comment: What do you mean? In the code above I set the filename to be the Title of the page and save it to a folder called "ExtractedText" as individual html files. What I want to be able is to instead name the file "counter".html where counter = the number of callbacks made to date. **How do I effectively keep track of the counter when a local variable would be re-initialised each time I execute the callback function

Comment: You can use `request.meta` dictionary, increase the value of the counter in the dictionary, this would work under the assumption that callbacks are processed sequentially

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure but I think you can't rename the scrapy image files however you want, scrapy does that.

What you want to do looks like a job for `CrawlSpider` instead of `Spider`.

CrawlSpider by itself follows every link it finds in every page recursively and you can set rules on what pages you want to scrap. Here are the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example).

If you are stubborn enough to keep `Spider` you can use the meta tag on requests to pass the items and save links in them.

```
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
        item=crawlerItem()
        item['url'] = response.urljoin(link.get('href'))
        request=scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.scrape_page)
        request.meta['item']=item
        yield request
```

To get the item just go look for it in the response:

```
def scrape_page(self, response):
    item=response.meta['item']
```

In this specific example the item passed `item['url']` is obsolete as you can get the current url with `response.url`

Also,

It's a bad idea to use Beautiful soup in scrapy as it just slows you down, the scrapy library is really well developed to the extent that you don't need anything else to extract data!

Comment: Thanks for responding, I'm not too concerned with the image files, its just the response text I'm really interested in. Is it possible with crawlSpider to specify it follow just the "a" tags as I can't say in advance I only want `category\.php` style links. The sites I want to crawl are not that structured

Comment: yes, if you specify no linkextractor but a callback, you can parse every link it goes through `Rule(callback='parse_item', follow=True)`

Comment: And finally how I create a unique identifier for the filenames that isn't based on the page title?

Comment: You have to create a [FilesPipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#using-the-files-pipeline)

Comment: If this answer satisfied you, please consider accepting it :-)

Comment: Could I trouble for a bit more help. when I run the updated code above I get  the error `ImportError: No module named files`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113738/discussion-between-rafael-almeida-and-mobcdi).