# How to get variable out of a yield callback function in Python

Tags: python, scrapy

I've been trying to figure out how scope and variables work in Python. I have been trying to solve this problem and I cannot find a way to get a variable out of a callback.

```
def parse1(self,response):
    return 1

def parse2(self,response):
    returned = yield Request(
       'https://www.example.com',
       callback=self.parse1,
       dont_filter=True
      )
    print str(returned)
```

Returns

```
1
```

I have tried to work with globals but variables set inside do not become global.

How can I get variables out of the callback?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37593508/7177029)?

Comment: I know about metas. But it doesn't solve my problem. I need returned in parse 2 with data from parse 1.

Comment: so simply put data in meta and get it in response in parse1()

Comment: But I needs to get printed in parse 2 not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking looks pretty specific to Scrapy and not Python, and in a Scrapy Spider what you want (blocking a request to wait for the response of another request) does not work this way, because of the underlying Scrapy machinery.
While you can `yield` a Request, the returned `Request` object and it's callback will only be processed once it is passed down to the underlying machinery, before you can get a Response result passed to your other parse method.

If, OTOH, you actually just want data from one method in the other, and "figure out how scope and variables work in Python", just call it:

```
def parse1(self,response):
    return 1

def parse2(self,response):
    returned = self.parse1(response)
    print str(returned)
```

But I'm guessing that's not your acual goal and your example is just bad.

What you're likely looking for, instead, is to wait for a blocking request to `parse1`, to return a response result to `parse2`, where you want to continue processing it. That does not work in the async world (it equals going back in time), and you'll rather want to *refactor your code* to not require this style; or if you find yourself depending on a synchronous, blocking, programming model, to use something other than Scrapy.

However, that being said, you can take a look at [scrapy-inline-requests](https://github.com/rmax/scrapy-inline-requests), which will help you being lazy; but to successfully use it you still need to understand the deeper Scrapy system and the problems that can crop up with using this. Avoiding it may save you headaches in the future. *Consider yourself warned.*
(*Definitely* read the "Known Issues" of the project Readme, and the Readme here: [flake8-inline-requests](https://github.com/stummjr/flake8-inline-requests/blob/260cace2252ebe92d8da7e1d57914cce4f8bc0b2/README.md).)

Using this, you can have inline requests and avoid writing multiple parse methods, like this:

```
import scrapy
from inline_requests import inline_requests

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'
    start_urls = ['http://httpbin.org/html']

    @inline_requests  ###<- using this
    def parse(self, response):
        urls = [response.url]
        for i in range(10):
            next_url = response.urljoin('?page=%d' % i)
            try:
                next_resp = yield scrapy.Request(next_url, meta={'handle_httpstatus_all': True})
                ### you can then do that ^^^^^^^
                urls.append(next_resp.url)
            except Exception:
                self.logger.info("Failed request %s", i, exc_info=True)

        yield {'urls': urls}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to put data in `meta`? Like `Request('https://www.example.com', callback=self.parse1, meta={'value': 0})` and then get it in `parse1` with `response.meta`.

Comment: I don't want to get it in parse1. I want to output something in parse2. This is a very simplified example to explain my problem.